# Stacked column chart in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have data in a sheet like the image below.

[image: The data format in the spread sheet]

The relevant portions are subtasks, shown in column B, subtask times, shown in column I, and daily totals, shown highlighted in green in the row at the start of each day's data.

Note that the general pattern is a daily total row followed by that day's subtasks.  However, each day can have a different number and mix of subtasks.

I am trying to create a stacked column chart, with one column for each day.  The gist is illustrated in the sketch, below (although the values and series don't exactly match the portion of the spreadsheet shown above).

[image: A sketch of the chart]

The chart shows times aggregated by task.  Tasks are defined by the character portion of the subtask name to the left of the hyphen in column B of the spreadsheet.  So, for example, ABUDHABI is a task that has values in each day's column.  On 09-02-16 in the sample data, it has five component subtasks that will be aggregated.

The task times may add up to less than the total workday (the green rows).  In that case, the difference would be included as a "dummy" task called "Overhead".

What I'm having difficulty with is extracting and aggregating the pieces and putting them into a form for Excel to turn into this type of chart.

Comment: Any chance you could mock up what you're looking for, even if you draw it in crayon on a napkin and snap an image with your cell phone?  It's hard to visualize from the description.

Comment: @fixer1234 I will try :)

Comment: @fixer1234 Here you go :)

Comment: Damn, you're good with a crayon!

Comment: @fixer1234 The chart only shows the general concept and somehow matches the data in the given sheet.
The B column specifies the data group and the I column the amount. All ABUDHABI-nnnn should be grouped in the same group and only show as a single part of the column.
The problem is mainly how to get the relevant data from the sheet but also how to add them to the chart. 
I hope it clerifies it a bit.

Comment: So basically, it looks like you need to aggregate some values from col I based on parsed values in col B?  If the subtasks don't match the total hours, how are they reconciled (or do you mean don't worry about the total, just base the chart on the subtasks)?  Is this something where the data will continue to expand and the chart needs to grow, or you have static data?

Comment: @fixer1234 The height of the column should be based on the total hours, not the subtask. But, the subtasks should be visible in the column. The remaining space in the column can just be added to an "overhed" category.

Comment: Excel builds the column from the component values.  So if the height is determined by the value in the green row, The component values will have to be calculated.  It sounds like you're saying if the subtasks add up to less than the green total, the extra goes into a series called "overhead"?  Can the subtasks add up to more than the green total?  If so, how do you want to prorate them so the sum matches the total?

Comment: @fixer1234 That is true. The subtasks will always be less or equal to the green total.

Comment: The question is pretty clear at this point.  I'll have to look at a solution when my brain is fresher.  Hopefully, you'll get some answers in the meantime.

Comment: Do you have control of the spreadsheet and are you willing to change your data layout to accomplish this?  The major issue you seem to have is pretty common-it looks like you're trying to capture data and report it from the same place (worksheet in this case).  It will be much easier to break data collection and data reporting into linked-but separate-pieces.  In this case, an Excel Table for data collection and Pivot Table for reporting/charting.

Comment: @dav Will I still be able to report the data in this table then? If so, the reporting can absolutely be placed in another linked sheet :)

Comment: You can do almost anything in Excel, but sometimes the solution can get "big".  If you can restructure your data, an approach like Dav's answer is definitely the way to go.  Starting from the existing structure would require a solution that is probably beyond what somebody will create for you within the scope of an answer on Super User.  There's a lot of complexity a solution needs to deal with.  The site is focused on solving specific problems.  This would be more a case of creating a mini-application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that requires a minor edit of your data collection table.

1. Re-format table with only necessary columns and rows (i.e. NO summary/subtotal rows).  I've added two columns, one to calculate your subtask, based upon your detail column.  The other calculates your overhead time by looking to see if there's a delta (created by a start/end time in your tasks) and if not subtracting your total committed time per day from 8 (assumed work day length).
2. Convert table to an Excel Table, `Insert > Table`.  This table will grow automatically as you add your data-it is your data collection point.
3. Insert a Pivot Table using your Excel Table as a data source, `Insert > Pivot Table`.  It can be on the same or a different worksheet.
4. Format your Pivot Table, with:

   - Row Labels = Date
   - Column Labels = Subtask
   - Values = sum of time.
5. Insert a Pivot Chart using your Pivot Table as a data source, `Insert > Pivot Table > Pivot Chart`.  The layout and formatting should follow your pivot table and provide the detail your looking for.

As you add data to your table, simply refresh your pivot table and it will add columns/rows for new dates or subtasks.  If you filter your Pivot Table or Chart, the other will follow so you can look at date ranges or specific tasks.

Here's a quick sample:

[image: Subtasks Chart]

Comment: Nice job.  One suggestion.  For some reason, the daily "totals" in the question don't appear to be a consistent amount, like 8 hrs.  Capturing the data in a better format is a good idea.  Perhaps the exact "overhead" should be entered as a subtask.

Comment: Thanks, and good point. The formula in the time column actually does look for a value in the "overhead" subtasks delta and adds it if explicit or uses the difference to 8 hours otherwise.

Comment: One other thing that isn't clear is how you parse the task from the subtask names.